# Infinite loop when putting rewrite into Directory context in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I want to redirect www.example.com/foo to www.example.com/bar/index.php/foo

So I have the rule (mod_rewrite)

```
<Location />
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule /(.*) /bar/index.php/$1 [L]
</Location>
```

This config caused a infinite loop, how to fix?

Thanks.

Comment: You should use RewriteMatch first.

Comment: See Redmumba's answer for how to fix. This is why: "Remember, however, that if the RewriteRule generates an internal redirect (which frequently occurs when rewriting in a per-directory context), this will reinject the request and will cause processing to be repeated starting from the first RewriteRule." (mod_rewrite docs for [L]).  Your rule is saying to redirect *every* request to /bar/index.php/$1, then this becomes a request, so it is redirected to /bar/index.php/$1, then this becomes a request...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Ency suggested, you'll want to make sure that you insure you're NOT trying to access `index.php`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/bar/index.php/.*
RewriteRule /(.*) /bar/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: When I removed <Location />, seems working without adding your Line2

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding the RewriteCond: 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}             ^Mozilla.*Chrome.*$

That should prevent the infinite loop* by executing the redirect only when the request comes from a browser.

*- Am assuming apache redirected request will either have an empty http header HTTP_USER_AGENT/apache, not the original header. 
P.S: you might want to add ie's http header to the list.